# Numpy: index array by array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
>>> idx = np.random.randint(2, size=(9, 31))
>>> a = np.random.random((9, 31, 2))
>>> a[idx].shape
(9, 31, 31, 2)
```

Why is the above not resulting in at least a shape of `(9, 31, 1)`, or even better `(9, 31)`? How can I get it to return a selection based on the values in `idx`?

**Update**

This is perhaps a more concrete and hopefully analogue example: Assume this array

```
a = np.asarray([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]])
```

How would I go about selection the array `[1, 4, 5, 8]` (i.e. the 0th, 1st, 0th, 1st element of each row)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
>>> a[np.arange(9)[:, None], np.arange(31), idx].shape
(9, 31)
```

For your second example you would do:

```
>>> a[np.arange(4), [0, 1, 0, 1]]
array([1, 4, 5, 8])
```

Read [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) on fancy indexing, especially the part on what happens when you don't have an index array for each dimension [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing): those extra `np.arange` arrays are placed there to avoid that behavior.

Note also how they are reshaped (indexing with `[:, None]` is equivalent to `.reshape(-1, 1)`) so that their broadcast shape has the shape of the desired output array.

Comment: So in other words, the np.arange() is making sure each row is selected. But why is `a[:, [0, 1, 0, 1]]` not the same (applying Python indexing logic (which may be wrong for numpy))? I'd really like to avoid creating a new array (`np.arange`) for the selection process.

Comment: If you applied Python indexing logic to `a[:, [0, 1, 0, 1]]`, it would raise a `TypeError: indices must be integers, not tuple`... ;-) What `a[:, [0, 1, 0, 1]]` means in numpy-speak is "for every row of `a`, create a four item array, that holds the first, second, first again and second again elements of that row." So there is really no alternative to creating the `np.arange` arrays. It is still ridiculously fast, so you really needn't worry about it.

Comment: Indeed, it seems very different to Python indexing. Thanks for the `numpy` translation. What does `a[np.arange(4), [0, 1, 0, 1]]` translate to? Intuitively it is still the same as `[:,]` to me...

Comment: Because `np.arange(4)` and `[0, 1, 0, 1]` have the same shape, and there is one array per dimension, the return will be an array of that same shape, `(4,)`, where each array is used to index the dimension it occupies, i.e. you would get an array with `[a[0, 0], a[1, 1], a[2, 0], a[3, 1]]`. It is tricky and even unintuitive to get the hang of it, but once you do it is very, very powerful.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your insightful explanations. I'm slowly getting there... ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You're doing advanced indexing on the ndarray http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing.

> Advanced indexes always are broadcast and iterated as one:

This is triggered because in your case the number of elements in the ndarray-index is not equal to the number of dimensions in the ndarray you are indexing into. Effectively you're producing an outer-product of slices: each element in your index produces a slice of the indexed array and not an element.

UPDATE:

```
>>> map(lambda idx: a[idx[0],idx[1]], [[0,0], [1,1], [2,0], [3,1]])
```

This will return:

```
[1, 4, 5, 8]
```

Comment: Hmm... that's not what I wanted. I'd much rather have it return a view on the array. But how can I use an array to determine the indices being selected?

Comment: I'm more interested in a `numpy` way to do the selection. Creating another list is not an option as the array is quite large.