# Numpy: Why advance indexing of > 2 dimensional arrays with a list and numpy array give different results

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have 3-dimensional numpy array

```py
a = np.array([
  [
    [1, 3],
    [0, 2]
  ], 
  [
    [2, 1],
    [4, 2]
  ]
], dtype=np.int32)
```

And I want to get the elements using the indices [0, 1, 1], and [1, 0, 1]

which I expect to give me:

```
[2, 1]
```

If I index with list, it returns the result I wanted, but if I index with Numpy array, it gives different results, why is that?

```
>>> indices = [[0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
>>> indices_arr = np.array(indices, dtype=np.int32)

>>> a[indices]
# OUTPUT
# array([2, 1], dtype=int32

>>> a[indices_arr]
# OUTPUT
'''
array([[[[1, 3],
         [0, 2]],

        [[2, 1],
         [4, 2]]],


       [[[2, 1],
         [4, 2]],

        [[1, 3],
         [0, 2]]],


       [[[2, 1],
         [4, 2]],

        [[2, 1],
         [4, 2]]]], dtype=int32)
'''
```

Comment: `(a[0][1][1],a[1][0][1])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy: index array by array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28980345/numpy-index-array-by-array)

Comment: I guess this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47826874/numpy-array-indexing-with-lists-and-arrays?noredirect=1&lq=1

and this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46116568/numpy-array-indexing-list-index-and-np-array-index-give-different-result

answered my question.

Comment: The list case is run as `a[tuple(indices)]`.  That's an old behavior that developers would like to get rid of.

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo, with `numpy` we can write that as `(a[0,1,1], a[1,0,1])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a  current numpy version `indices` gives a warning:

```
In [46]: a[indices_arr].shape
Out[46]: (3, 2, 2, 2)

In [47]: a[indices]
C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8668\2035022355.py:1: 
FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; 
use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted 
as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  a[indices]
Out[47]: array([2, 1])
```

doing the tuple conversion myself:

```
In [48]: a[tuple(indices)]
Out[48]: array([2, 1])
```

Your `indices_arr` is the different result it warns about.

With `tuple, we are applying each sublist to a separate dimension of` a`:

```
In [49]: a[[0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
Out[49]: array([2, 1])
```

With `indices_arr`, the array is applied to just the first dimension, hence the (2,) becomes (3,2).

Comment: Thanks, I now understand this.

Is there any way to get the result I wanted without converting the Numpy array to a tuple? For performance benefit, I'm trying to avoid `for` loops and extra memory allocation (which I think what conversion to tuple does).

That is to get the result `[2, 1]` with `np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]], dtype=np.int32)`

Comment: One way I could think of is multiplying the index with the size of the array, then use `np.sum` and `np.take` to I can get the result with `np.take(a, np.array([3, 5], dtype=np.int32)`

Comment: Python and numpy indexing is built around the concept of providing a tuple - one value (index,slice or array) for each dimension.  The interpreter translates `x[i,j,k]` to `x.__getitem__((i, j, k))`.  It gives the getitem method a tuple.  Why is your index an array to start with? Why not a tuple like that produced by `np.nonzero`?  Or `np.ix_`.